# Python \b character acting strangely

Tags: python-3.x

I noticed that the \b (backspace) character was acting a little strangely. I usually run code in Google Colab, where the following code runs like:

[image: Colab output]

But when I run it on my own computer, it acts completely differently:

[image: Other output]

Does anyone know why that is happening, and is it possible to get the behaviour of the first image locally?

Comment: Please do not post code as images when not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree about the code. It could have been posted as text. However, it might have been necessary to post images of the output since this is a rendering issue.

Comment: Here it indeed is, and I apologize. Your observed behavior of `\b` has been long known to me, so it completely escaped me somebody might be puzzled by it.

Comment: (I mean possibly erratic behavior of `\b` when compared from one output method to another. For laffs, you may want to repeat your program and write the output to a file. Then you will see the same bytes get send either way, so this will prove it's the local *output* that matters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a python thing. It depends on whatever rendering comes after python hands it over for printing. Python simply gives the stream a sequence of characters. And it is up to the terminal or Google Colab to render it appropriately.

Then `\b` character instructs whatever is printing to move the cursor back one character, then you continue writing. It is not "backspace", it is "left arrow" if anything.

Your first print types `a` then moves the cursor to the left of `a` then types `c`, thus overwriting `a` with `c`. This prints the expected `c`.

The next print types `d` then moves the cursor to the left, then stops. This is the interesting print. In a terminal the print ends here, thus this line prints `d`. And the next print starts from scratch.

That means in a terminal the last line says to move the cursor left, there is no left there, so it is a NOP operation, then enter `e`. Which just prints  `e`.

However, Google Colab seems to either keep the cursor alive between prints (I doubt it), or it sends a new line character using the same cursor which overwrites the `d`.

Without knowing exactly how it renders text it is hard to say.

More info can be found here: [Python strings: backspace at the end of string behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732236)

**Edit**: Looking even more closely at it, it seems that it might just be a known issue with notebooks: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5381#issuecomment-614982643

Seems like it is conflating `\b` as "backspace" instead of "left arrow" as I talked about in the start.